# Converting elastic search query to rest call parameters

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I am working on `kibana` and `elasticsearch`. I indexed the documents in `elasticsearch`. Now, I want to create an UI and make it searchable like here:

```html
GET /complete_index/_search
{
  
 
   "query":
   {
     "multi_match": {
       "query": "broker connection",
       "operator":"and",
       
       "fields": ["post_subject","topic_title"]
       
     }
    
   
 },
 "from": 0,
 "size": 50, 
 "_source":  ["post_id","topic_id","post_subject","topic_title"]
}
```

I cannot pass the `elasticsearch` query as data to rest call. How can I correct it?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715720/how-to-convert-curl-into-uri-in-elasticsearch/34715809#34715809

Answer (score 0):

Use curl request to make rest calls to Elasticsearch, like below.

```
curl -XGET "https://f03cadb8fd043aa17dcce6850f4646e7.ap-southeast-1.aws.found.io:9243/complete_index/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"broker connection","operator":"and","fields":["post_subject","topic_title"]}},"from":0,"size":50,"_source":["post_id","topic_id","post_subject","topic_title"]}'
```